# Very simple question related to Java syntax

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, bitwise-operators

**Could someone explain me what is the meaning of following symbols in the following line :**

symbols       **|      <<**

`long high = (System.currentTimeMillis() << 16) | 0x4000 | random.nextInt(4096);`

How is the value of `high` calculated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<<` is used to shift bits, in this case left arrow for shifting left

`|` is used for bitwise-OR, which means given two operands, it will set the output bit position to 1 if either or both of the operands have a 1 in a particular position

System.currentTimeMillis() returns 32-bits, this shifts it to the left

```
xxxxxxxx yyyyyyyy zzzzzzzz aaaaaaaa
becomes
zzzzzzzz aaaaaaaa 00000000 00000000   (where the right bits are all 0's)
```

And the 0x4000

```
0x4000 in HEX = 01000000 00000000 in BINARY
```

random.nextInt(4096) produces an int just shy of 4096, so it can produce any combination of the bits

```
0000???? ????????   // where each ? can be randomly 0 or 1
```

So all in all,

- how is the value of high calculated ?

It is made up of these components

```
zzzzzzzz aaaaaaaa 0100???? ????????  // binary representation of the long var (4 bytes)
```

- z's and a's are the lower 16 bits from the current time
- the 0100 is exactly that sequence
- the 12 ?'s are generated randomly (0 or 1)

Answer (score 3):

<< is a bitwise shift operator, you can read more about that here: http://www.sap-img.com/java/java-bitwise-shift-operators.htm.

| is the bitwise inclusive or which you can read more about here: http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/bitwise-bitshift-operators.shtml

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is a bitwise shift operator. See: [Java Tutorials: Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: And the pipe (|) is the bitwise-OR, also mentioned on that page.

Answer (score 1):

"<< 16" means shift the bits of the value (currentTimeMillis) 16 positions to the left.

"| 0x400" means bitwise-OR that value with the bits 0x400

Answer (score 0):

The symbols are

> | = or
>
> << = Bit shifting to the left

So basically the high value is a binary operation